# jquery loop through children relative to parents and so on

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am working on some extension for a webpage and it has layout something like this.

```
<div class ="contents holder">
    <name1 id="id1">
        <name2 class="class1"> 
            <div id="content">
                <itemslist class="class3">
                    <div id="contents">
                        <renderer class="class4"></renderer>
                        <renderer class="class4"></renderer>
                        <renderer class="class4"></renderer>
                    </div>
                </itemslist>
            </div>
        </name2>
    </name1>
</div>
```

what i want is to loop through renderer items and i can do something like this.

```
    $( 'renderer' ).each( function() {} );
```

But i want to specify the renderer from its parents and specify the parent from its parents and so on.
something like this.

```
contents holder(class) --> name1 --> class1(class) --> 

content(id) --> itemslist --> contents(id) ---> renderer
```

and then loop through all renderer items. how do i do this.

Comment: Having multiple elements with the same ID in the same document is **invalid HTML**. Consider fixing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain any id or class combination you want

```
$("#someid .someclass .someotherclass renderer").each ()
```

This will loop all renderers nested in that id and class chain